# Testing injected dependencies into your struts2 actions

Tags: spring, testing, struts2

I am wondering how others might have accomplished this. I found in the Spring documentation @required which I attempted to use in a 'test' but got this stmt INFO XmlConfigurationProvider:380 - Unable to verify action class [xxx] exists at initialization

I have found another way in spring to do this is to write custom init methods and declare those on the bean but it almost seems like this is a strange thing to do to a struts2 action.

In my application I inject through spring different web services (via setter injection) into different actions. I want to ensure on startup these are not null and set.

Comment: I think I can further refine my question. In struts2 since most actions are stateful there beans are scoped 'prototype' This makes @required and when I try writing custom init methods log the statement above unable to verify class exists at initialization. when I change to singleton my 'checks' work and the application fails to startup. I cannot find any methods in my searches for testing prototype scoped spring beans at startup to ensure dependencies are set.

Comment: I think you may need to provide more details - perhaps your spring config file. Are you saying that the (prototype) action is not present when your test is looking for it, or is it one of the dependencies that isn't there?

Comment: Yes - after reading more on prototype scope my understanding is these are created when the action is requested so at startup they are not available which is why I get the error message above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `request` or `session` spring scopes.

Then you can do the checks in a `@PostConstruct` method, what will you do there? Throw an exception? Well,  something isn't set you will eventually get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: What I wanted to do was not allow the application to startup. After reading more about @required it does allow for null values so as a test I wrote an init method and used the spring assert functionality to say that a certain dependency was not null and if it is display an error message.  You are right eventually I do get an NPE with prototype scope when the action is called but I would prefer to know there is an issue at startup. When I changed the scope to singleton(as a test) and used the init method I did get the desired behavior where the error was thrown and startup failed.